# Worker Loader in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker, worker-loader

This is my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import Worker from 'worker-loader!../../workers/app.worker'

class MyComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        let worker = Worker()

        worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
            console.log('succes', e.data)
        })

        worker.postMessage('please work')

    }

    render = () => {

        return(<div>Not That Relevant</div>)
    }
}
```

my very simple worker:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
self.addEventListener('message', e =>{
    console.log(e.data)
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
    self.postMessage(e.data);
})
```

The instantiation of the worker inside of the component leads to an empty Worker, i.e. :

```
Worker {onmessage: null, onerror: null}
```

Needless to say: it doesn't do anything, and the app.worker path is correct.

Plus since I imported the loader I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at bootstrap:1
    at bootstrap:791
```

so I think the `worker-loader` is messing with the webpack-config in some way.

Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: Why do you use arrow function as render? It should be function expression - `render() {`

Comment: Why not? I don't think it is that relevant in this case.

Comment: As far as I know it's one of React principles, to use lifecycle hooks as class methods, not class fields (not arrow functions). It may lower your app performance.

Comment: Could you try using the usual onmessage api of the webworkers ? `worker.onmessage = e => { console.log('success', e.data) }` in the main js and `onmessage = e => { console.log(e.data); postMessage(e.data) }` in the worker, never used self for a worker FWIW.

Comment: @MaximeR. it is actually not doing anything.

Comment: I think `Worker` is a class that needs to be instantiated using `new Worker()`